# Does placing buildings next to the coast work in Clash of Clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Upon visiting the village of someone who attacked my village I noticed that they had placed their buildings next to the coast, with only three sides of the building surrounded by walls.  The coastal side had no wall.

Does this strategy work?  Will attacking enemies not simply walk onto the beach and attack the un-walled side?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This a good question, and pretty much every new player gets duped into doing this at one point or another.  The answer is "the edge of the world is not a wall".  You can try for yourself and see that when attacking you can drop troops outside the edge of the map.  Villages that attempt to use the edge as a boundary quickly learn it doesn't protect you.

Source: Personal Experience

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)   Time to go and quickly re-arrange my town before my shield runs out.

Comment: lol coming from boom beach I did the same and got radied :D

Answer (score 2):

It works to some degree because the edge of the world can be more difficult to place troops. Sometimes deployment requires multiple taps instead of holding down your finger to release troops. Not being able to unleash your army in a timely manner can mean less percentage destruction. You don't have the massive firepower you normally would by holding down your finger to release troops.

Comment: Not sure how any of this is related to a village bordered by the perimeter area which was increased to two tiles in early 2016. The only slight impediment is that many people do not salvage the stone or trees in the perimeter area. While you can drop on those items, troops do navigate around them.

Comment: If you look at when I answered the question Jun 2013, the increase in tiles around the edge were not in effect. You're commenting on an answer that was a point in time. Your comment while valid Mar 2016 is not a fair criticism of the answer from almost 3 years when the context and play system CoC differs from the present.

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to update your answer.

Comment: No. Feel free to add your own answer if you think you can contribute something better.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a good strategy to put builder huts in opposite two corners especially during war. If some attackers doesnot pay attantion to them and deploys all his troops for the main village, if you get completely destroted, those two huts can save your 100% damage and thus a star as time runs out before attacker troop go there and finish them too.

Obviously if your attacker is a good scouter, then he can put one archer on each in the beginning and then start his real game.